# CentOS Latex - Install package manually (no tlmgr)

Tags: texlive

I've installed LaTeX via

`sudo yum install tetex-latex tetex-doc tetex-fonts`

and

`sudo yum install texlive tex-live-latex`

(of course removing one before trying the other.

The installations work giving my LaTeX on my server but I don't seem to have tlmgr.

I need to install the tikz package manually on the server and can't seem to find any information on how exactly this is done without the use of tlmgr.

Any CentOS users that know the proper way to install LaTeX on my server and get the tikz package installed manually?

Comment: Not on CentOS, but I doubt yum gives you tlmgr.  If you want it, it is better to install 'vanilla' TeX Live from CTAN (many questions here about that).  Otherwise, does the command `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFHOME` return anything?  If so, that's the system-level home, while `TEXMFLOCAL` and `TEXMFHOME` respectively reveal the local and personal homes. You can install into any of these directories. (Questions here should address relative benefits of each.). Note files ending `.tds.zip` are the easiest to install manually. Finally, `tetex` is almost certainly too old, even on CentOS.

Answer (score 6):

Most distributions' TeX Live packages do *not* ship `tlmgr` for good reason, as it would interfere with the package managing tools. You should use the distribution tools to install, update, and manage TeX Live packages.

Some distributions *do* ship `tlmgr` and let it work in specific mode. Debian for example ships `tlmgr` but sets it automatically to user mode, which means that one can manage one's `TEXMFHOME` (or any other directory) with it. Afair there are other distributions that download the TeX Live package and repackage it into an rpm and then install it, but I think that CentOS is not doing this.