# LaTeX Error: File "XCharter.sty" not found

Tags: errors, packages

I'm using TexMaker on Xubuntu.

When I try to compile my file `.tex`, TexMaker says `LaTeX Error: File XCharter.sty not found`.

This error is in line 23, which says `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`.

Could someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Is `xcharter` installed?

Comment: How can I know if is `xcharter` installed?

Comment: TeX Live Package Manager (tlmgr) tells you, normally.

Comment: What if I don't have tlmgr? Then how do I tell if xcharter is installed?

Answer (score 4):

Open a Terminal. Then:

```
tlmgr Install xcharter
```

In some cases, you may need this, instead:

```
sudo tlmgr Install xcharter
(then provide password)
```

You may also need to intall this package: ly1

In the preamble:

```
\usepackage{XCharter} % capital X capital C
```

Tested and works for me, with article class, either pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Many distributions do not include `tlmgr` as [this answer explains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289609/14402).